# How to read from file in python using more than 1 core

Tags: python, multithreading, file-io, multiprocessing

I have 2 files with random numbers, and I need to find all numbers from file 1 Which are not in the second.
I know how to do it in a single process, it's easy, but I must use 2 or more cores for this task.
Can someone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to use two CPUs? Do you think it will be faster?!

Comment: Are you willing to do lots of synchronization between the two threads?

Comment: @Aron, may be it is not faster, but a have a task to involve two or more cores. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of threading tutorials online. Try this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Pseudo code:

```
import thread

def useFile(fin):
    while(true):
        line = fin.readline()
        if line == "":
            break
        #do something with line

with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
    thread.start_new_thread(useFile, (fin))
    thread.start_new_thread(useFile, (fin))
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not using multiple cores.. it still uses 1 core with interuptions between running tasks

Comment: @PYPL Actually you almost have to change threading to multiprocessing to make it work. If you absolutely have to use threads you are going to have to rewrite the GIL!